# Pagination in Angular UI Bootstrap throwing "Error: [$compile:nonassign]"

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using a fairly simple implementation of Angular Bootstrap UI's pagination directive, yet I keep getting an error I cannot figure out. Here's the relevant snippets:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="todo in filteredIdeas">
    {{todo}}
  </li>
</ul>
<pagination ng-model="currentPage" total-items="totalIdeas"></pagination>
```

Here are the relevant portions of my $scope in the controller:

```
// Set watch on pagination numbers
$scope.$watch('currentPage + numPerPage', function() {

  var begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.numPerPage);
  var end = begin + $scope.numPerPage;

  $scope.filteredIdeas = $scope.ideasData.slice(begin, end);

});


// Data
$scope.ideasData = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  $scope.ideasData.push('To do ' + i);
}

$scope.filteredIdeas = [];
$scope.currentPage = 1;
$scope.numPerPage = 10;
$scope.totalIdeas = $scope.ideasData.length;
```

The pagination sets itself up correctly, but here's the error I receive when trying to click on the next page (or any page for that matter):

```
Error: [$compile:nonassign] Expression 'undefined' used with directive 'pagination' is non-assignable!
```

If I understand correctly, this is indicating that I'm using something improperly for two-way binding? Was able to replicate the bug in this Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/uyWQXPqjLiE4qmQLHkFy

Anyone have any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Heres your plunkr forked: http://plnkr.co/edit/BNgdbXD5YVwPKGhuIYcN?p=preview

Comment: I like your $watch, but imo this is better:
http://plnkr.co/edit/79yrgwiwvan3bAG5SnKx?p=preview

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The ability to use `ng-model` was introduced in `ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.js`, as explained in the [changelog](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/commit/a81d6f986ad123d1fe68f5750d4b22f0da193654):

> Both `pagination` and `pager` are now integrated with `ngModelController`.
>    * `page` is replaced with `ng-model`
>    * `on-select-page` is removed since `ng-change` can now be used
>     Before:
>       `<pagination page="current" on-select-page="changed(page)" ...></pagination>`
>     After:
>     `<pagination ng-model="current" ng-change="changed()" ...></pagination>`

Since you are using `ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.min.js`, you need to use the old syntax - with `page` instead of `ng-model`:

```
<pagination page="currentPage" total-items="totalIdeas"></pagination>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to give concrete example:

```
 <uib-pager total-items="totalItems" items-per-page="4" ng-model="currentPage" ng-change="pageChanged()"></uib-pager>
```

and then tie pageChanged in your scope:

```
$scope.pageChanged=function(){
      console.log("Current page" + $scope.currentPage);
  };
```